# Explanation regarding the use of offset in read calls

Tags: java, inputstream

I found this code in order to encode the file into base64.  It is using an offset.

```
File filePath = new File("/sdcard/videooutput.mp4");
try{
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(filePath);
    long length = filePath.length();
    // Create the byte array to hold the data
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
    // Read in the bytes
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset<bytes.length && (numRead=fin.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset))>=0){
        offset += numRead;
    }
    // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+filePath.getName());
}


Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

What I do not understand about this code is `while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=fin.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0)`.

Can anyone explain what the code is trying to do?  I only understand it check whether the offset is less the length of the bytes and the rest I am not sure.

My next question is, what is the reason for using the offset to encode the file?

<sub>Any answers regarding this questions would be really helpful.  Sorry for asking this type of question but I really need to understand this code.</sub>

Comment: The offset isn't "used to encode the file", it's a counter of where in the file you're reading from. Play computer: write down the values for the variables as the code "executes" on paper. There's no encoding happening in the code snippet provided, just reading.

Comment: Instead of using the `offset`, you can use `DataInputStream`

Comment: That's not encoding it to base64. If you want to do that, then you can use the core `javax.xml.bind.DataConverter`, or Apache Commons Codec.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee im sorry. i've re-post my post. the encoded happening after reading the offset.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati can i used dataInputStream for video file?can it also upload the file?

Comment: `DataInputStream` has a `readFully()` method. Check it out. It reads into a byte array

Answer (score 1):

[InputStream#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

`int numRead=fin.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)`

read fills the given byte array, starting at the given offset, for the given amount of bytes. However it's not guaranteed that even if you request 100 bytes, that you will get them. So this code is basically incrementing the offset after each call to read().

The intial call will attempt to fill the byte[] completely. If that fails, it moves the offset forward by the number of bytes that were successfully copied and trys to fill the byte[] starting at the new offset. Each new attempt it only trys to read enough to fill what's left in the buffer.

Comment: thanks @Greg. so, let me recap back what i understand from this. offset is the starting point to read the file. meanwhile the bytes is the location where it placed all the read bytes. so, if i want to get the value of the byte that been read, i should use bytes. am i right?

Comment: If you truly want the last single byte read, it will be in `bytes[offset - 1]` Otherwise all the read stuff will be in the array, `bytes[]` by the end of the loop. So you can just look in that array for the last contents